# magento 2 unknow column not found in category

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 I created custom category attribute it working fine like Yes or No attribute

when I try to get in the collection

```
$collection = $this->_categoryModel->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('status','0')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('searchcategory', 'Yes')
            ->setOrder('position','ASC');
```

it throws the error

```
**Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'searchcategory' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `mps_category` AS `main_table` WHERE (`status` = '0') AND (`searchcategory` = 'Yes') ORDER BY position ASC**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding **->addFieldToSelect('searchcategory')**

```
$collection = $this->_categoryModel->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToSelect('searchcategory')
            ->addFieldToFilter('status','0')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('searchcategory', 'Yes')
            ->setOrder('position','ASC');
```

This is guessing, maybe it works for you.

Comment: still same error Error filtering template: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'main_table.searchcategory' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `main_table`.`searchcategory` FROM `custom_category` AS `main_table` WHERE (`status` = '0') ORDER BY position ASC

Comment: Why custom_category? this is not category table. Something wrong in your end.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake I wrongly checked